# How can I do string interpolation?

Tags: html, angular, string, typescript, string-interpolation

I'm trying to do string interpolation in code using Angular, Typescript, HTML, etc... For some reason the 'dollar sign' appears as a string literal in the output. Can anyone help?

I need the output to as follows:

> "Hello World."

Instead, I'm getting this:

> "Hello ${name}."

Link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-template-string-interpolation

Thanks.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend reading https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax, or even just starting with https://angular.io/tutorial

Comment: @bela: Yes, that is the correct answer. I had tried it with the wrong characters before. That's why it failed.

Comment: @jon: Thank you. Those links are very informative. I'll give them a thorough read.

Answer (score 6):

To interpolate strings, you need to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Template literals use ``` (backtick) and not `'` (single quote)

Also, `name` is a class property, so you should reference it by using `this`

So, your code becomes:

```js
title: string = `Hello ${this.name}.`;
```

Comment: I had the single quote character, and it should have been the backtick character. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3):

String interpolation only happens inside back ticks.

```
"Hello ${name}."
```

produces `Hello ${name}.` but

```
`Hello ${name}.`
```

produces `Hello previewFrame` in your example. This is because you are referencing the wrong variable. Instead of `${name}` use `${this.name}` otherwise you're getting the name of the frame that stackblitz renders your output in.

For the record, this is not a typescript or Angular feature. String interpolation is a newer vanilla javascript feature. [More info here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the **this** keyword and the back ticks. Like this:

```
title: string = `Hello ${this.name}.`;
```

Comment: I had the single quote character, and it should have been the backtick character. Thank you for the help.